# Is starbound a single world with different characters?

Tags: starbound

What I mean is the following. If I have two characters, Derp and Herp, and I build a house with Derp on a given planet, will Herp be able to see the house also if they travel to that planet's coordinates?

Comment: Planets don't have coordinates, sector locations do. (As in, everything you see on the nav computer screen at once.) You can find a specific planet by the star system name. (It should also be on the same location on said screen.)

Comment: +1 for naming your hypothetical characters Herp and Derp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. The game has one universe and all your characters, and their buildings, exist in the same one. Anything you build will sync on the server or PC you build it on.

Comment: All games have the same universe. You can share coordinates with other players. (In Minecraft parlance, the coordinates are the "world seed" for the sector location: http://starbounder.org/Notable_Coordinates.)

Comment: @millimoose As someone who's interested in but not played the game, do you mean *all games ever* are in the same universe, MMO-style? Or all games you play *on your computer*?

Comment: Also, your link grabbed the period at the end. You want [http://starbounder.org/Notable_Coordinates](http://starbounder.org/Notable_Coordinates), no period

Comment: @dlras Neither. All games played on the same server/computer are tied together, as 3ventic described, but what millimoose was saying is that every single system will generate the same worlds with the same initial layout at the same coordinates.

Comment: @dlras2 — The **starting state** of each game is completely identical, the whole thing seems to be procedurally generated from a nonrandom seed. Since the planets are where you play, and the starting state of each star system is generated from its location, this means you have a bajillion "randomly" generated planets. Anyone who you share coordinates with will see the planet as you first saw it – anything you mine out or build etc. is stored locally.

Comment: @dlras2 — Also, interestingly, the notion of *MMO-style* kind of breaks down (or will break down) in games like [No Man's Sky](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2013/12/09/first-look-no-mans-sky/). Which uses a universe that's procedurally generated in the above way, but also has indirect multiplayer interaction similar to I'd say Dead Souls, where changes to a planet will actually be visible to other players, even if you never meet them.

Comment: *"the whole thing seems to be procedurally generated from a nonrandom seed"* - Close; the coordinates themselves are the seed.  The difference is that this way they didn't have to pre-generate millions of worlds...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In Starbound, there is just 1 universe, and all your characters, and their home planets, exist there. However, going from the home planet of 1 character to the home planet of another will probably take thousands of fuel, so it doesn't really affect gameplay that much. So, in your "Herp" and "Derp" example, it would probably take days for Herp to gather enough fuel to do so.

Comment: Are you sure? IIRC, starting planets are the same for all characters, so chances are you'll be close to any bases you built (unless you travel really, really far from where you start). Additionally, if you get a couple of engineers, after a while you're paying almost literally zero fuel when you warp, even when travelling across the entire universe.

Comment: @MageXy Every character uses a different starting planet. I created a test character and built a small base, and it wasn't present when I started a new, actual character, plus the planet layout was different. They have certain features in common (e.g. presence of the mine mini-dungeon), but they're still randomly generated.

Comment: @Michaellogg Oh, okay. That must have changed in the 1.0 release, earlier versions definitely had each character starting on the same planet.