# Can I transfer items between my characters in single player Starbound?

Tags: starbound

Based on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146038/is-starbound-a-single-world-with-different-characters) about a shared universe/planets, I began wondering if you can transfer items between your own characters without an intermediary on a server.

Currently at work and unable to test, but has anyone accomplished this and how did you do it without items despawning?

Comment: It should be possible by using a chest on a planet where both of the characters are, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the world seed for each server or local game is the same thing, and the universe (as a whole) is the same for each planet, it would be possible.

To do this, you'll need to know what X/Y location you're on for the galaxy map.  Then, find what planet you're on.  When you have found that, place a chest on that planet and put your stuff into it.  Then, log onto the new character.  With the new character, fly to that location and then grab the stuff.