# When are planets generated in Starbound?

Tags: starbound

In the patch notes for [Offended Koala (Dec 15, 2013)](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/changelog-for-v-offended-koala-15-12-2013.52997/) it notes

> - Fix naked NPC merchants

On my starting planet I had an Avian village that included several of these naked NPC merchants who would let me interact with them but have nothing to sell.  I started this game before the patch hit, and afterwards I revisited the village and they were all still naked, all still had nothing to sell.

So my question is when do planets actually get generated?  According to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146038/is-starbound-a-single-world-with-different-characters) all characters on my local system will share the same universe.  Is a planet's generation based on when your universe was created or do these get generated only upon visiting them and then will be generated based on the current patch?  If I start a new character will it also find these naked merchants?  If so, how do I fix this?  Do I need to delete my universe folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The map generates as you explore it by rules set by the game (same locations always look the same in same version of the game). The whole planet is not generated at once, but in smaller chunks. This can be seen if the server can't keep up with your exploration.

If you create a new character, that same planet, which previously had naked merchants, will continue to have naked merchants. You can fix it by regenerating your universe by deleting the universe folder.

Comment: So do I need to delete my universe folder for planets to generate in the new way or do they start generating once the patch is applied?

Comment: @Krjax the existing world will not be replaced by a new patch unless the patch wipes the saves, so yes, you will need to delete at least parts of the universe folder to regenerate the worlds you want to.